# Orchard Upload Documents w/TinyMCE

Tags: tinymce, orchardcms

I know Orchard contains a built-in set of options for TinyMCE with uploading media, but is there an equivalent for just uploading standard documents that is similar so users can link to them in the editor?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried TinyMCE Deluxe?

http://gallery.orchardproject.net/List/Modules/Orchard.Module.TinyMceDeluxe

You can use any of the official pluggins

Comment: I'm already using that but it doesn't have a document uploader built-in (that I've seen).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [TinyMceDeluxe](http://gallery.orchardproject.net/List/Modules/Orchard.Module.TinyMceDeluxe), as mentioned, which lets you use TinyMCE plugins. Then, you can use a TinyMCE plugin to get the functionality you need. Here are some of the options that I'm aware of:

- [MCFileManager](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/MCFileManager)
- [TinyBrowser](http://www.lunarvis.com/products/tinymcefilebrowserwithupload.php)
- [Ajax file/image manager](http://www.phpletter.com/Demo/Tinymce-Ajax-File-Manager/)
- [PDW File Browser](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdwfilebrowser/)